# I want to load specific div form other website in php

Tags: php

I have a problem to load specific div element and show on my page using PHP. My code right now is as follows:

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results");
    preg_match('/<div id="results-data" class="fixtures-table full-table-medium">(.*)<\/div>/is', $page, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

I want it to load id="results-data" and show it on my page.

Comment: What did you try, what where the results?

Comment: And where exactly is the problem? You've got the regex.

Comment: Use a HTML parser instead of a regular expression

Comment: it show me null array.. but there are 4 to 5 table inside the div...

Comment: You should also use curl and mask your useragent and add a bbc referrer else your server most likely get blocked as its most likely against there tos...

Comment: is there any example that how to use curl to load this div into my page 
<div id="results-data" class="fixtures-table full-table-medium"></div>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to manipulate the URL to get only a portion of the page. So what you'll want to do is grab the page contents via the server-side language of your choice and then parse the HTML. From there you can grab the specific DIV you are looking for and then print that out to your screen. You could also use to remove unwanted content.

With PHP you could use `file_get_contents()` to read the file you want to parse and then use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse it and grab the DIV you want.

Here's the basic idea. This is untested but should point you in the right direction:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'content') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use some html parser. Take a look at PHPQuery, here is how you can do it:

```
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results');
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
$resultData = pq('div#results-data');
echo $resultData;
```

Check it out here:

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery

[Also see their selectors' documentation.](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Selectors)

Comment: I get the following error
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/results) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: ....respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected

Comment: @Rizwanabbasi: That's fault on bbc side, there server goes down or some other reason.